# Difficulty in recognizing relative path in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to react js and i have a react js application with this file structure on windows operating system

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jbn5.png)

[Index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7WP.png)

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xghhj.png)
And i keep getting this error message

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBrEd.png)

Module not found: Can't resolve '../../features/event/EventDashboard' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\react-apps\revents\src\app\layout'

Please who has faced this type of error before

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
../../features/event/EventDashboard
```

to

```
../../../features/event/EventDashboard
```

Because after moving parent folder (../) twice, you are in **app** folder not **src** folder

Comment: Thanks i found the problem i did not include the file itself, so i changed ../../features/event/EventDashboard to ../../features/event/EventDashboard/EventDashboard.